# IIS output caching causing wrong pages to display

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I turned on output caching in IIS7.5 for .aspx pages but sometimes when I browse to PageB.aspx I see the output for PageA.aspx. Looking on google this seems like it's a common issue but no one has said if they have fixed it or how.

How can I enable output caching but avoid this issue? Is there a variation I can add in the settings (querystring or headers) or is there a hotfix for this issue?

**update:** If I add "Accept" to the Vary By Headers setting, it works better, but not 100% because pages with the same Accept header will have the issue.

**update:** if I add "Accept, Referer" to the headers, it looks like everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://forums.iis.net/p/1152323/1883773.aspx) in the rewrite engine. The following command should fix it:

`reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Rewrite /v RewriteCacheEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0`

You'll need to run `iisreset` after this command.

Comment: Thats a pretty old source and looks like it's for iis 7. Is it still applicable to 7.5 and the latest rewrite module?

Comment: The registry entry is the same and has the same effect. However, my understanding was that the bug was fixed in the latest rewrite module. You seem to still be experiencing precisely the same symptoms though, so it's worth testing if the same fix works for you. (If not, remove the registry entry, since it does have a small negative effect on performance.)

Comment: It looks like even with the change you suggested I still have the same problem. That really sucks.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll do some more research and see if I can find another lead for you.

Comment: far to unreliable. had to turn it off 100%. Unfortunate.